# Org-Ref: How to custom bibtex-completion-fallback-options

Tags: org-ref, helm-bibtex

How do we customize `bibtex-completion-fallback-options` in `init.el`?

The following code gave rise to the error below:

```
(add-to-list 'bibtex-completion-fallback-options
         `("NTU Library 台大圖書館                           (web)"
     . "https://ntu.primo.exlibrisgroup.com/discovery/search?query=any,contains,%s&tab=LibraryCatalog&search_scope=MyInstitution&vid=886NTU_INST:886NTU_INST&lang=zh-tw&offset=0"))
```

```
Helm issued errors: helm-match-from-candidates in source `Fallback options': wrong-type-argument (buffer-or-string-p (NTU Library 台大圖書館                           (web) . https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=%s))
```

I know one way is to do this through custom: `C-h v bibtex-completion-fallback-options`. But I'd like to learn to write some `elisp` code on my own.

---

How do I add a second item to the list? The second variable is not registered after a restart.

```
(add-to-list 'bibtex-completion-fallback-options
         `("NTU Library 台大圖書館                           (web)"
           . "https://ntu.primo.exlibrisgroup.com/discovery/search?query=any,contains,%s&tab=LibraryCatalog&search_scope=MyInstitution&vid=886NTU_INST:886NTU_INST&lang=zh-tw&offset=0")
         `("Academia Sinica 中央研究院圖書館                           (web)"
     . "https://las.sinica.edu.tw/search*cht/a?searchtype=t&searcharg=%s&SORT=D&submit.x=0&submit.y=0"))
```

Comment: Your example works fine. Have you changed the value of `bibtex-completion-fallback-options`  elsewhere?

Comment: Oh, I think I ran a similar code with an extra pair of brackets around the variable before this, and it is that code that is giving rise to the error. It works fine with the current code after a restart. Thanks!

Comment: You can add only one element using `add-to-list`. IOW if you need more elements added, repeat the code from the first example. You also don't need the backquote since there's nothing to evaluate in the list. Use a single quote instead.

Comment: On another note, is there a way to jump to the Fallback Options section when browsing your bibtex file?